# How to remove missingMethod route when using Route::controller() in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes, laravel-routing

When I use `Route::controller()` it will automatically generate a route like: `GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE resource/{_missing}`.

this will make conflict if I have route like `resource/{id}/somethingElse`.

**Sample code**

```
<?php

Route::controller('page', 'PageController');

Route::Group(['prefix' => 'page/{id}/comments'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'CommentController@index');
    Route::post('/', 'CommentController@create'); // <-- this will not work sometimes I don't know why
});
```

The line I highlighted throws `NotFoundHttpException` with `Controller method not found.` message.

Is there anyway to remove that route containing `{_missing}` parameter?

Comment: Maybe switching the order helps. Register the `Route::group` first and the `Route::controller` afterwards... And why aren't you using `Route::resource`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter, they are in separate package, I switched order of packages service provider in app.php with no joy. and the page routes are not mine to edit (I do not have permission to change them :p)